# Groceries sample app ('end' branch) errors out during compile

Tags: android, mobile, nativescript

I am trying hard to get started with NS and want to see the final Groceries app working in a local android emulator on Windows 10. But, I am getting the following in my command window after attempting to execute tns run android --emulator:

```
:processF0F1DebugResources
C:\Projects\fixxly\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\F0F1\debug\v
alues-v21\values-v21.xml:216 : AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resour
ce found that matches the given name 'NativeScriptToolbarStyleBase'.

:processF0F1DebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processF0F1DebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:     org.gradle.process.internal.E
xecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Dboude\AppData\Local\Android\android-sd
k\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I have performed the following routine in order to try and make NS happy:

1. uninstalled my JDK via control panel, uninstalled Android SDK via Android Manager, uninstalled NS; walked back through the NS 'getting started' tutorial and allowing NS to install JDK and android

I've googled my head off and cannot divine what the true core issue is. If anyone has any hints at what to try, I'm all ears!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is related to this [enter link description here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/1209)

However in order to resolve it try the following steps:

- Upgrade to the latest NativeScript releqase

  ***npm install nativescript -g***
- in your sample-Groiceries root folder delete ***node_modules*** and ***platforms***

  ***rm -rf platforms/ node_modules***
- run the following

  ***tns install***
- add the platforms needed

  ***tns platform add android***
- add the lastest modules

  ***tns plugin remove tns-core-mudules***

  ***tns plugin add tns-core-modules@latest***
- rebuild your app

  ***tns run android***

Basicly this will clean your project form previour versions and will install the latest modules

Comment: I appreciate the input Nick! I followed your instructions, and still got the same error. I think rather than jump straight to the 'end' branch I'm just going to have to build the groceries app from scratch by following the tutorial. Hopefully THAT will work! I sure was hoping this would be a little less painful, but it is what it is. Thanks again.